# How do I build a loop into this TimeStamp VBA Code?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to build a loop into this code.

When I paste into the range it's referencing it will only update the first value I've pasted, and not update for the any of the other cells. Is there an easy way to loop this so it will continue onto the next cell that doesn't equal a blank in the row and update when I paste a range of cells?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim xCellColumn As Integer
Dim xTimeColumn As Integer
Dim xRow, xCol As Integer
Dim xDPRg, xRg As Range
xCellColumn = 2
xTimeColumn = 9
xRow = Target.Row
xCol = Target.Column
If Target.Text <> "" Then
    If xCol = xCellColumn Then
       Cells(xRow, xTimeColumn) = Now()
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        Set xDPRg = Target.Dependents
        For Each xRg In xDPRg
            If xRg.Column = xCellColumn Then
                Cells(xRg.Row, xTimeColumn) = Now()
            End If
        Next
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Please let me know if there's anything else I can provide.

I was expecting a timestamp function that I would allow for pasting ranges into the workbook to note the time. It's not updating save for the first cell in the pasted range.

Answer (score 1):

`Target` is a range, meaning it can contain multiple `Areas` and each `Area` can contain multiple `Cells`. You could loop through those two collections applying your changes to each cell individually.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xCellColumn As Integer
    Dim xTimeColumn As Integer
    Dim xRow, xCol As Integer
    Dim xDPRg, xRg As Range
    xCellColumn = 2
    xTimeColumn = 9
    
    Dim Area As Range
    For Each Area In Target.Areas
        Dim Cell As Range
        For Each Cell In Area.Cells
            xRow = Cell.Row
            xCol = Cell.Column
            If Cell.Text <> "" Then
                If xCol = xCellColumn Then
                   Cells(xRow, xTimeColumn) = Now()
                Else
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set xDPRg = Cell.Dependents
                    For Each xRg In xDPRg
                        If xRg.Column = xCellColumn Then
                            Cells(xRg.Row, xTimeColumn) = Now()
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            End If
        Next Cell
    Next Area
End Sub
```

You might want to add an exit condition if `Target` is too large. If the user makes a large worksheet edit, like clearing an entire column, this event might cause unnecessary slowdowns.

Comment: You are a Hero, thank you!